# Can't SSH my artik board, disk full

Tags: ssh, arm

I have ubuntu running on Samsung Artik ARMv7.

One of my apps generated a lots of logs, and a failing logrotate strategy provoked the board to be full.

Boards are 300km away from me, so let's say access them physically is possible but have a cost I would like to avoid.

How should I deal with it ? with the same board, I have several weeks with those space issue, but this is the first time I lose SSH access.

a while after:

```
ssh root@192.168.23.13 -p 53535 -vvv
```

I get:

```
Connection closed by 192.168.23.13 port 53535
```

Is there anything I can do ?

Comment: You can try to reboot the system without login - `ssh root@192.168.23.13 -p 53535 'systemctl reboot'`. If this succeed the `/tmp` directory will be freed and probably you will be able to login. Or you can try to remove the files in the log directory - `ssh root@192.168.23.13 -p 53535 'rm /var/log/*'`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm trying it, will tell you in short if it worked

Comment: it didn't work :(